# Integrating current density for cylindrical symmetry

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, maxwell-equations

Considering a constant current density, $\vec{J}=\frac{I}{A}\hat{k}$, and also assuming there is no displacement current in the situation, how would one apply Maxwell-Ampere's law? I keep running into infinite field whenever I try this approach:

$$\oint_c \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl} = \mu_0(\iint_S(\vec{J_e}+\epsilon_0 \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t})\cdot \vec{dA})$$
$$\oint_c \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl} = \mu_0\iint_S\vec{J_e} \cdot \vec{dA}$$
$$\oint_c \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl} = \mu_0\iint_S\hat{J_e}J_e \cdot dA\hat{J_e}$$
$$\oint_c \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl} = \mu_0\iint J_e dA$$
$$\oint_c \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl} = \mu_0\iint \frac{I}{\pi r^2} rdrd\theta$$
$$\oint_c \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl} = \mu_0\iint \frac{I}{\pi r} drd\theta, 0<r<a$$
$$\oint_c \vec{B} \cdot \vec{dl} = \mu_0\int \frac{1}{\pi}ln(\frac{a}{0}) d\theta = diverges$$

Comment: Is your your current density $\vec{J}$ meant to be zero for $r>a$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your current density is
$$\vec{J}=\begin{cases}
\frac{I}{\pi a^2}\hat{k} &, \text{ for } 0<r<a \\
\vec{0} &, \text{ for } r>a
\end{cases}$$

The mistake is in the step where you replace the current density $J_e$
by $\frac{I}{\pi r^2}$. It should rather be $\frac{I}{\pi a^2}$.

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C \vec{B}\cdot d\vec{l}
&= ... \\
&= \mu_0 \iint J_e\ dA \\
&= \mu_0 \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^a \frac{I}{\pi a^2}r\ dr\ d\theta \\
&= ... \\
&= \mu_0I
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly the issue :)